# GIN jsonb_path_ops index not used in nested JSONB array

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a JSONB column `content` with the following structure:

```
{
  "sections": [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three"
  ],
  "other_field": "other_content"
  }
```

I need to filter the rows based on whether a tag is contained in `sections`, and I've been doing so by using the `@>` operator.

I added this index:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS sections_gin_idx
    ON inter.users
        USING gin ((content->'sections') jsonb_path_ops);
```

If I run:

```
explain analyze select * from inter.users where content -> 'sections' @> '["one"]';
```

I see that it's actually doing a seq scan. Any help is appreciated!
I am using Postgres 15

Comment: That should work just fine. To test if the index can be used, run `SET enable_seqscan = off;` first (there may be too few rows in the table).

Comment: Additional question now that it runs as should, why does it do a Bitmap Index Scan and a Bitmap Heap Scan?

Comment: That's how GIN indexes are always scanned, since the scan is "lossy" (can return false positives). The recheck during the bitmap heap scan takes care of that.